# How to copy mock object in scala test?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have below situtation. Will this work?

```
case class Person(name: String)
val person = mock[Person]
val anotherPerson = person.copy(name = Some("name"))
anotherPerson shold not be null
```

Comment: Why would you mock such a class? Just use it.

Comment: If your class under test is `Person` you obviously should not mock it, as this is what you are testing. If you are testing some other class that uses `Person`, then just create instance of `Person` and use it, no point to mock a class with no behavior.

Comment: Sometimes there are too many irrelevant arguments for a given test, I think question still stands